# Issue with the React App with S3 listObjectV2 and headObject calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am learning React and can't figure out what is causing the issue below. I want to get a a list of files using AWS SDK listObject method and then modify the array to include the user defined metadata that is retrieved by the headObject method.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

import "./App.css";

function App() {

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION,
    },
});

const params = {
    Bucket: "abc",
};

const [listFiles, setListFiles] = useState([]);

const theadData = [
    "user_metadata_1",
    "Name",
    "Size",
];

useEffect(() => {
    const files = s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
          } else {
            setListFiles(getUserMetaData(data.Contents););
          }
    })

}, []); //end of use effect

function getUserMetaData(files)
{
    let aFile;
    files.forEach((aFile) => {

    const headParams = {
        Bucket: "abc",
        Key: aFile.Key,
    };
s3.headObject(headParams, (err1, data1) => {
    if (err1) {  
        console.log(err1, err1.stack);
    } else {
        aFile.user_metadata_1 = data1.Metadata["user_metadata_1"];
     }
       });
     });
return files;
};

return (
    <>
        <div className="App"\>
            <table>
                  <tr>
                        <th>user_metadata_1</th>
                        <th>Document Name</th>
                        <th>Size</th>
                  </tr>
          {listFiles &&
                listFiles.map((name, index) => {
                  return (
                        <tr key={index}>
                              <td>{name.user_metadata_1}</td>
                              <td>{name.Key}</td>
                              <td>{name.Size}</td>
                        </tr>
              );
            })}
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
    );
}
```

export default App;

I am able to get the data but I can't seem to display the updated array in the table. The table displays the data(array) that does not include the "user_metadata_1". Also, the HTTP calls seem to be repeated, i.e 2 HEAD request for every file and "/?list-type=2" call for the listObject method.

Comment: Show a screen shot

Comment: Added the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbkel.png. I think this is happening because the API calls in the For loop are not finished before the method returns.